# Fail2ban regex on a variable string

Tags: regex, fail2ban

im getting mad!
i want to take make a rule to match the "5.7.1" from postfix the "reject body" string and then ban the ip. Here is the string from maillog.

Sep 10 08:04:57 server postfix/cleanup[11430]: 7793A80D7F97: reject: body Se non desiderate ricevere queste raccomandazioni: Rimuovere me  - from cha129.probionicapps.com[188.208.198.129]; from= to= proto=ESMTP helo=: 5.7.1 Spam Succesfully Rejected - WE REFUSE SPAM AGENCIES -   004

i need a regex rule to get the ip and ban it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add this regex to postfix.conf:

```
^.*\[<HOST>\].*\shelo=:\s5\.7\.1\s.*$
```

Verify it works as expected by running:

`fail2ban-regex -v /var/log/mail.log "^.*\[<HOST>\].*\shelo=:\s5\.7\.1\s.*$"`

or, if you save it to postfix.conf:

`fail2ban-regex -v /var/log/mail.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/postfix.conf`

Comment: why can't I just simply write `.*shelo` ?